# How to create similar enum class in scala

Tags: scala

This is how my enum class looks like in java. How do I create same in scala?

```
public interface EmployeeDataField {
int getPosition();
boolean isMandatory();
String name();
}

public enum EmployeeJobDataField implements EmployeeDataField {
EMP_ID(1, true), LOGINID(2), FIRST_NAME(3),
MIDDLE_NAME(4), LAST_NAME(5),
FULL_NAME(6), JOB_LEVEL(7)

EmployeeJobDataField(final int position) {
    this(position, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommended way is to used a `sealed trait` and `case object`s:

```
sealed trait MyEnum
object MyEnum {
  case object One extends MyEnum
  case object Two extends MyEnum
}
```

If you need to have a list of all enums, `"String"` to value, etc, add to it [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) library

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait MyEnum extends EnumEntry
object MyEnum extends Enum[MyEnum] {
  case object One extends MyEnum
  case object Two extends MyEnum

  val values = findValues
}
```

If you want to initialize each value with some parameter you can use `sealed abstract class`

```
sealed abstract class MyEnum(val someValue: Int)
object MyEnum {
  case object One extends MyEnum(1)
  case object Two extends MyEnum(2)
}
```

`sealed abstract class` can also be used with enumeratum.

If you want you can add methods to it.

```
import enumeratum._

sealed abstract class MyEnum(val someProperty: Int) extends EnumEntry {

  def someMethod: Int = someProperty * 2

  def someAbstractMethod: String
}
object MyEnum extends Enum[MyEnum] {
  case object One extends MyEnum {
    def someAbstractMethod: String = "a"
  }
  case object Two extends MyEnum {
    def someAbstractMethod: String = "b"
  }

  val values = findValues
}
```

Theoretically, Scala has a build-in `Enumeration` but it has many issues and is discouraged nowadays:

- values of `Enumeration` are just values so we cannot check if match is exhaustive

  ```
  object MyEnum extends Enumeratum {
    val One, Two = Value
  }

  (myEnum: MyEnum) match {
    case One => ...
    // no error or warning on non-exhaustive match
  }
  ```
- you cannot make `Enumeration` values implement interfaces, add methods or properties - they are just sets of objects with overridden `toString` that can be compared for reference equality. The `object` itself has some useful methods, but so does enumeratum
- because of how it is implemented, type-class derivation for `Enumeration` is harder than for sealed hierarchies - for that reason many libraries don't support it at all

  ```
  @ import $ivy.`com.chuusai::shapeless:2.3.3`, shapeless._ 
  import $ivy.$                             , shapeless._

  // MyEnum doesn't exist as a separate type, which might be confusing
  // (MyEnum.type is the actual type of MyEnum object)
  @ Generic[MyEnum] 
  cmd7.sc:1: not found: type MyEnum
  val res7 = Generic[MyEnum]
                 ^
  Compilation Failed

  // and MyEnum.Value doesn't tell compiler anything useful
  @ Generic[MyEnum.Value] 
  cmd7.sc:1: could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic[ammonite.$sess.cmd0.MyEnum.Value]
  val res7 = Generic[MyEnum.Value]
                ^
  Compilation Failed
  ```

  If even libraries for type class derivation don't support it, you cannot rely on libraries using them to have that support. It can be done (I did it in [enumz](https://github.com/scalalandio/enumz)), but as far as I can say nobody does.

As a result many people independently reached conclusion that `Enumeration` doesn't work for them, while `sealed trait`s do. If they need extra methods (all values, name-to-value and value-to-name conversion, etc) they add enumeratum and call it a day.

In Scala 3 the [boilerplate will be reduced with `enum`s](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/enums.html):

```
enum MyEnum {
  case One, Two
}
```

which will bring a lot to the table (e.g. [compatibility with Java enums](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/enums.html#compatibility-with-java-enums) if you need it).

Comment: Care to expand on `Enumeration is discouraged`?

Comment: I added explanation for why `Enumeration` is discouraged